# Assistance in constructing a validating statement to identify a row in a column that is >= to a value or column y - which ever is greater

Tags: r, validation

Issue: trying to locate outlier data in a large data set -> I have used the programme validate to facilitate this and separate code to generate 'tails' for the data - columns called cd_hr_Day1_left and cd_hr_Day1_right

the validate 'rule' (cd_hr_Day1 > cd_hr_Day1_left & cd_hr_Day1 < cd_hr_Day1_right) works.

However I would like to develop the 'rule' and specify cd_hr_Day1 > cd_hr_Day1_left OR 55 which ever is greater

Any pointers on how to generate that as a logical argument.

````
library(validate)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

study_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
cd_hr_Day1 <- c(80,NA,105,45,78)
cd_hr_Day1_left <- c(70,70,70,70,70)
cd_hr_Day1_right <- c(85,85,85,85,85)

baseline_df_test  <- data.frame(study_id, cd_hr_Day1, cd_hr_Day1_left, cd_hr_Day1_right) 

test_rules <- validator( "cd_hr_Day1_outlier"= (cd_hr_Day1 > cd_hr_Day1_left & cd_hr_Day1 < cd_hr_Day1_right))

test_output <- confront(baseline_df_test, test_rules,key = "study_id")
summary(test_output)

test_dout <- as.data.frame(test_output)

test_missing_or_outlier_data <- test_dout %>%
  dplyr::filter(!value == TRUE) %>%
  dplyr::select(study_id,name) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(study_id)

test_missing_or_outlier_data %>% gt() ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use `pmax` in your `validator`.

`pmax` returns the parallel maximum of the input values. For example, if you try:

```
pmax(1:5, 3)
[1] 3 3 3 4 5
```

It will give the maximum value between 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 compared with 3. For the first three values, this is just 3. For 4 and 5, it is those values, respectively.

Likewise, you can use:

```
test_rules <- validator("cd_hr_Day1_outlier" = cd_hr_Day1 > pmax(cd_hr_Day1_left, 55) & 
                                               cd_hr_Day1 < cd_hr_Day1_right)
```

In this case, the maximum value between `cd_hr_Day1_left` and 55 will be included.